xargs cannot run with -n1 and -I together?
I need to create sub-folders under in selected_images with identical structure as download_async/. I used this command:
ls download_resave/ | xargs  -n1 -t -I{} mkdir -p select_images/{}

But I know this command is not precise since I saw the warning:
xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value

And I tried this:
ls download_resave/ | xargs  -n1 -t mkdir -p select_images/$0

This will not output a warning, but it will create in the current folder rather than the target folder.
Would you tell me what is the correct way using to do this with xargs? Besides, why the second command is not correct?

You picked the wrong thing to remove... -I{} implies -n1 - you wouldn't be able to use -n2 and -I{} together. Just get rid of -n1. Your last snippet fails because $0 is evaluated by your current shell and not passed to xargs.

(but also don't parse ls output, so... cd download_resave && find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p ../select_images/{} \; && cd .. should be more reliable)

Your ls/xargs will fail if a name contain space. You can use something like (cd download_resave && find -type d -print0) | (cd select_images && xargs -r0 mkdir -p)

@dimich What if the command requires two arguments,and I need -n2 to combine each two lines into the command ? How to write this ?

@coincheung It depends on how exactly you want to pair arguments. Maybe you can use sed, awk or other text-processing tools to join lines in required order.

@dimich+ with -I{} space (or tab) in any of the names is treated as data and does not fail, but quote or backslash (still) is either lost or causes an error, and newline causes a wrong result; find -print0 | xargs -0 is indeed safe for any char that can appear in a filename

@dave_thompson_085 Yes, you're right, space or tab is ok but newline in filename will be teated by xargs as an argument separator.

Not a programming problem, this belongs over at [unix.se] or [su].

The issue is that -n1 and -I can't be used together in xargs. The correct command to create sub-folders in select_images with the same structure as download_resave/ is:
ls download_resave/ | xargs -I {} mkdir -p select_images/{}

Why the second command didn't work is because $0 refers to the script name, not the argument passed to xargs. You need to use {} as the placeholder for the argument, not $0.

how could I make it work, if the command I requires two arguments, and I need -n2 to create the two arguments?

Though don't use ls here.

For xargs to consume two arguments each time, try this :
echo "arg1 arg2" | xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo Hello $1 world $2' _
# output:
Hello arg1 world arg2

